# import multiple xml, xls to database > edit > then export to one xml file

Tags: xml, database, architecture

please help me with this question. 
Maybe there is such working software, or it need to be created from scratch? If so - maybe you comment if it is real to create such database?

We have several diferent xml files from different manufacotries. Aditional we have some xls files with product data. We need to import all this info to one database. Then we will edit these data, add some margin, select catagories, etc. And then we need to export all data into one (or multiple) xml file.

Data are with 100.000-200.000 goods description, prices etc.

Please answer if this task is real to do, if so - in which software, platform it is better to make?
Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You are talking about standard process of [**ETL**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extract,_transform,_load)

- **Extracts** data from homogeneous or heterogeneous data sources
- **Transforms** the data for storing it in the proper format or structure
  for the purposes of querying and analysis
- **Loads** it into the final target (database, more specifically, operational data store, data
  mart, or data warehouse)

You can try to use this Open Source Tools:

- Talend Open Studio for Data Integration.
- Pentaho Data Integration includes the Kettle application.
- Jaspersoft ETL
- KNIME
- Apache NIFI
- Rhino ETL
- StreamSets

If you are familiar with the programming it's may be more convenient to implement simple ETL steps in your own app.